# How to get the total number of tasks changed by an ansible playbook run?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to get the number of tasks changed so far using some ansible module or a fact? I would like to run a task if anything was changed prior to its run.

Comment: When _anything_ changed, or do you actually only care if _certain_ things change? Because there are modules in ansible that get marked `changed: yes` even if they didn't exactly mutate the underlying system (`command:` is certainly one, there are likely others)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I just want to run `etckeeper commit` in the latest task of the play if Ansible reports that anything was changed so far. In fact I solved that already by running `git status` prior to `etckeeper commit`.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to record your Ansible runs in some way to collect the data of previous runs. There are 2 well-known options:

1. ARA Records Ansible
2. AWX/Ansible Tower